# Merge the object using typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, merge

In my angular application i am having the data as follows,

```
  forEachArrayOne = [
    { id: 1, name: "userOne" },
    { id: 2, name: "userTwo" },
    { id: 3, name: "userThree" }
  ]

  forEachArrayTwo = [
    { id: 1, name: "userFour" },
    { id: 2, name: "userFive" },
    { id: 3, name: "userSix" }
  ]

  newObj: any = {};

  ngOnInit() {
this.forEachArrayOne.forEach(element => {
  this.newObj = { titleOne: "objectOne", dataOne: this.forEachArrayOne };
})

this.forEachArrayTwo.forEach(element => {
  this.newObj = { titleTwo: "objectTwo", dataTwo: this.forEachArrayTwo };
})

console.log({ ...this.newObj, ...this.newObj });


  }
```

In my real application, the above is the structure so kindly help me to achieve the expected result in the same way..

The **working demo** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gyched which has the above structure.

Here `console.log(this.newObj)` gives the last object,

```
   titleTwo: "ObjectTwo",
   dataTwo:
     [
       { id: 1, name: "userFour" },
      { id: 2, name: "userFive" },
      { id: 3, name: "userSix" }
     ]
```

but i want to combine both and need the result exactly like the below..

```
  {
  titleOne: "objectOne", 
  dataOne:
    [
      { id: 1, name: "userOne" },
      { id: 2, name: "userTwo" },
      { id: 3, name: "userThree" }
    ],
  titleTwo: "ObjectTwo",
  dataTwo:
    [
      { id: 1, name: "userFour" },
      { id: 2, name: "userFive" },
      { id: 3, name: "userSix" }
    ]
}
```

Kindly help me to achieve the above result.. If i am wrong in anywhere kindly correct with the working example please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning both values to `this.newObj`, so it just overwrites the first object.

Also, there is no need for your loop. It doesn't add anything.

Instead, you can do:

```
this.newObjA = { titleOne: "objectOne", dataOne: this.forEachArrayOne };
this.newObjB = { titleTwo: "objectTwo", dataTwo: this.forEachArrayTwo };
console.log({ ...this.newObjA, ...this.newObjB });
```

** 
**EDIT** **

Having spoken to you regarding your requirements, I can see a different solution.

Before calling `componentData`, you need to make sure you have the full data. To do this, we can use `forkJoin` to join the benchmark requests, and the project requests into one `Observable`. We can then subscribe to that `Observable` to get the results for both.

The code would look something like this:

```
 createComponent() {
    let benchmarks, projects;
    let form = this.productBenchMarkingForm[0];
    if (form.benchmarking && form.project) {
      benchmarks = form.benchmarking.filter(x => x.optionsUrl)
        .map(element => this.getOptions(element));

      projects = form.project.filter(x => x.optionsUrl)
        .map(element => this.getOptions(element));

      forkJoin(
        forkJoin(benchmarks), // Join all the benchmark requests into 1 Observable
        forkJoin(projects) // Join all the project requests into 1 Observable
      ).subscribe(res => {
        this.componentData({ component: NgiProductComponent, inputs: { config: AppConfig, injectData: { action: "add", titleProject: "project", dataProject: this.productBenchMarkingForm[0] } } });
      })
    }
  }

  getOptions(element) {
    return this.appService.getRest(element.optionsUrl).pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        this.dataForOptions = res.data;
        element.options = res.data;
        return element;
      })
    )
  }
```

**[Here is an example in Stackblitz that logs the data to the console](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpdcnc)**

Comment: But in my project i have structure like this only.. So only i have explained with foreach.. Also mentioned the same in my question that is the structure i am using..

Comment: Also i know this solution already but that is not in my case.. I making the code as like in my question...

Comment: Okay, well at the moment your question doesn't give enough information for me to answer. Can you give the actual structure of your data then please? Then  maybe I can understand why you need to use a loop.

Comment: If not this one possible, Kindly help me how to correct the above code.. Because i am passing the ```newObj``` to another component in angular so i need to assign both separate values to the ```obj``` and to get in that component..

Comment: I have updated the question.. Here i am loading the another component so am sending data via that ```componentData``` and i am getting it in ```this.injectedDataFromComponentOne``` inside component two.. But the thing is i am getting the second object value alone there as like i explained in my question..

Comment: A single variable such as this.injectedDataFromComponentOne can only hold one value, so as soon as you set the second object value it will overwrite the first value

Comment: Then how can i pass both values and get both the values in the ```this.injectedDataFromComponentOne```.. Kindly help me please stuck with this one for a long..

Comment: It depends what you need to do. You could always add both of the values into an array and send an array instead?

Comment: If it is benchmarking, then i need to send benchmarking data and if it is project theni need to send project data and i need to get both at the ```injectedDataFromComponentOne```...

Comment: Well if you need 2 separate values, why not use 2 separate variables?

Comment: All the time i will have both benchmarking and project and i need to send different data for these two.. So i am assigning the data to ```componentData``` in both the conditions..

Comment: As i am using dynamic component loader, ```this.componentData``` will load the component with the data we are passing..

Comment: I also updated my question with ```componentData``` function which loads the component in dynamic and assign data..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183844/discussion-between-user184994-and-undefined).

Comment: I am suffering a lot in it please help me with right approach to handle it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398213/angular-form-with-array-of-input-elements

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392659/create-inputs-as-array-in-angular-form